# Obtain "next to be used" id for a table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table with 2 int type columns: one auto increment and primary, while the other is just not null.

now, whenever a record is inserted into the tale, the first auto-increment column gets a unique and new id. What I want is that this new ID value to be also inserted to the other column, in the same insert statement.

How can a achieve this? Plz help...

thnx in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand why you need in this? However, you can create the second column also with autoincrement (but you should check if the values in these two columns are the same). Moreover, you can create a trigger that will update the value of the second column after the insert (this is the best way, I guess).

Comment: thnx... I need this bcoz in this table(it has other columns too), if in a record these two column values are same, then they represent parent, while in other cases it represents child. Thus, to add a parent element, i need this.

As u suggested i can u trigger. But, is it possible to use triggers in android SQLite?
My concern might seem a lil dumb as I have practically no experience in java, android and sqlite. Im from c,c++, linux background :(

Also, if it is possible, could u plz gimme a lil direction as to how should i proceed?

Comment: Yes, you can add triggers in Android. How to create databases in android you car read, for instance, here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html But there are also a lot of other places in the Internet. Just find what u prefer. To add trigger just add in the SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate additional execSQL method which should add a trigger to your table. About triggers: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Comment: Thnx @Yury , that was indeed helpful :-)